# How can I link libxml2 to a C project in Windows

Tags: c, linker, gtk, libxml2

I have to compile a project written in `C` under `Windows`, this project uses both `libxml2` and `gtk`

Using `Ubuntu` I compile it like that

`gcc 'pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 libxml-2.0' file.c ...`

Under `Windows` I downloaded and installed `gtk` and `libxml2` but compiling it says I've not `libxml2`. I added correctly these two packages to the `pkg-config` path, but I think I've not the correct `libxml2` cause it doesn't contain any `.pc`, like `gtk` do.

So where can I find the correct installer of `libxml2` for `Windows`?

Comment: What are you using for your build environment? MSYS, MinGW, VSCode?

Comment: I'm using MinGW

Comment: I haven't used MinGW in a while. Did you build `libxml2` from source, or use the MinGW installer tool (`mingw-get`)? Is there a separate `libxml2-dev` or `libxml2-devel` package available?